# Kohana framework. Kohana class question

Tags: kohana, php

I'm looking at Kohana framework and trying to go through the code to better understand how framework works.

So - from index.php we load:

```
require SYSPATH.'base'.EXT;
require SYSPATH.'classes/kohana/core'.EXT;
require APPPATH.'bootstrap'.EXT;
```

In core.php file we do the following:

```
public static $environment = Kohana::DEVELOPMENT;
```

What to we refer to by calling Kohana::DEVELOPMENT?
From what I understand - by using :: we should be getting static constant from kohana class. - right? But at that moment in the code there is no Kohana class loaded that I could find.
So - can someone explain what's going on here:) ?
Thanks

**RESOLUTION:**

never mind. I didn't follow the code far enough. Kohana class extends Kohana_Core class. mmm.  too bad there is no way to delete dumb questions from StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kohana (as probably any other framework) uses "auto loading" mechanism. This allows you to use classes without including the files they are defined in by hand. The autoloader will automatically include/require the file that the `Kohana` class is in.

So when you type `Kohana::DEVELOPMENT` or `new Kohana ();` the auto loader will load the file with the `Kohana` class in it. You should know that this does not work magically. You have to write your own auto loader code for your framework.

You can read more about auto loading [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

Comment: it uses php's spl autoloader. but it's not defined by that time in the code. it's defined later on in the code.

Comment: oupps. never mind. we don't use core class directly - but rather extend it later in code. duuh. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

For further information check this link: [spl_autoload register](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php). Kohana uses own implementation, which can be set in the `bootstrap.php` file. You can found this funtion in the `Core.php` file.

```
/**
 * Enable the Kohana auto-loader.
 *
 * @link http://kohanaframework.org/guide/using.autoloading
 * @link http://www.php.net/manual/function.spl-autoload-register
 */
spl_autoload_register(array('Kohana', 'auto_load'));
```